Confused about the results of a mixed effect model
I have a dataset of two continuous muscle activity levels A and B. I hypothesized that B is linearly correlated to A which is confirmed by a simple correlation test. And I have two categorical factors: subjects and tasks. I want to know if the linear relation (intercepts and slopes) vary by those two factors. So I constructed a linear mixed effect model: B ~ 1 + A + (1+A|subjects) + (1+A|tasks), and I did the following two steps:
1) I compared with and without those two random factors. The results show that having the subjects as the random factor significantly improves the residuals, but not with tasks.
2) I also check the ICC for subjects and tasks. The ICC for subjects is 0.0025 but the ICC for tasks is 0.67.
Now I am confused. Model comparisons indicate that differences between subjects are important to include but the ICC results suggest that tasks are mainly responsible for the variances.
How do I understand these results? Should I continue with tasks or subjects?
I would appreciate a lot if anyone could help me to sort this out. I must have understood some parts wrong.
Here are the details:

When comparing B ~ 1 + A with B ~ 1 + A + (1+A|subjects), AIC_compact is 864 while AIC_full is 764 with p value <0.001, indicating the random factor is significant beneficial. Similarly, when testing with and without (1+A|sections), AIC_compact is 864 while AIC_full is 870 and p value is not significant. (I sense maybe this step is problematic. Can I use this method to judge random factors?)
A and B are both continuous variables; they are the muscle activation levels during a task, say gripping. There are four tasks. In reality, it is hard to tell which task the subject would be doing. Hence, I consider it as a random factor. I assume that different tasks would only change the slope and intercept but overall it would be normally distributed (maybe this step is problematic too.)
I tried to consider tasks as a fixed effect, but the fitting cannot be done for some reason.

If you need any other information, please let me know.
Best
B

If you have sufficient sample size, no estimation issues and no colinearity issues, there is no reason to simplify the model. What do you mean the residuals improved? How did you assess this? It is not as straightforward as with ordinary linear models. And finally, could you include some information on the variables? I can understand why subject would be included as random, but are tasks a random draw of a larger set of possible tasks?

To follow up on the comment from @FransRodenburg, please edit the question to explain what the tasks variable represents. I suspect that it would better handled as a fixed predictor, perhaps included in an interaction with A, but it's hard to know without more information.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Thank you for your comment! I edited my question to include more details. If you need any more information, please let me know!

"Similarly, when testing with and without (1+A|sections)" - how is this different from the first comparison in item 1? Also note that if you don't only consider random effects for intercepts but also for slopes, ICC is not a reliable indicator of the strength of the effect. (And it seems to me rather important to understand how and why exactly modelling task as fixed effect went wrong.)

@ChristianHennig. Task is categorical and the A or B is continuous. When running the model with tasks as the fixed effect returns an error about ranking. I don't fully understand but it seems that the data is significant correlated to the tasks; hence they cannot do a ... ranking?
The first one is to consider subject as the random factor. So at this point, I am only testing single random factor, subject or section. Do you suggest me to do the full set with both subject and section in? I read that when using random factors, it is good to use full model. Is that what this means?

Are tasks and sections the same thing? Please edit your question so that this is clear (optimally use only one term for the same thing). At this point I don't have any suggestion other than understanding what the problem is with tasks as fixed effect, which I can't from the information given. For this it would be necessary to see the exact code run, error message, and maybe also the data. I can only say that I wouldn't base any decision on ICC here.

@ChristianHennig. Yes, section is task. Sorry, I missed that. But thank you for the answer!
